# Put Tabs inside a Fragment of the BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, kotlin

So I built an app which contains a BottomNavView with 4 different Fragments and 4 different layouts. (Home, Booklist, Recent and Downloads)

Now I want to put 3 Tabs inside of the first Fragment (which is the HomeFragment). I've found lots of Tutorials on how to implement Tabs inside AppCompatActivity, but what I want to do, is to put them inside the HomeFragment.

Code:
Currently, I have my BottomNavView in the activity_main.xml and the 4 Fragments (Home, Booklist, Recent, Downloads).
Then, I made 3 Fragments for the Tabs (ForYou, All, New).

Here is a GitHub link for all files: https://github.com/Oribakun/tabs-inside-fragment-test

This is my fragment_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextColor="#fff"
        app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="fixed"

        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is how my HomeFragment looks like:
I thought that this would work but I get the Error "Val cannot be reassigned" when hovering firstViewPager and tabLayout in line 46 and 48.

```
package fragment

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.mangami.mangami.*
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager


class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private val tabLayout: TabLayout? = null
    private val firstViewPager: ViewPager? = null



    /**
     * Initialize newInstance for passing parameters
     */
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): HomeFragment {
            val fragmentHome = HomeFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            fragmentHome.arguments = args
            return fragmentHome
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        firstViewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_home)

        tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs_home)
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(firstViewPager)

        setupViewPager(firstViewPager)
        return rootView


    }


    private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager) {
        val adapter = HomeFragmentTabAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(HomeFragmentForYou(), "For You")
        adapter.addFragment(HomeFragmentAll(), "All")
        adapter.addFragment(HomeFragmentNew(), "New")
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
    }

}
```

My Question now is: How can I put Tabs inside the Fragment?

By the way, I use Kotlin for everything.

I'm searching for a way to do this for a couple of days now. I'm sure there is a simple solution, I just can't find it so I'm counting on you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable as `val`, it is the same as declaring it as final in Java; once it's been assigned, it cannot be changed. In addition, `val`s declared on the class-level cannot be initialized from other methods than the constructor. <sub>Declaring a val in a method follows different rules; it needs to be assigned, but it doesn't need to be right away. The only requirement is initialization before accessing, but this is because vals and vars in methods are different than class-level ones</sub>

Which means, since you assign the val instantly, it's locked to be null. Since you try changing it in `onCreate`, you get an error because you cannot reassign a val that's already been assigned.

Which means, since you aren't assigning it in the constructor (/init block) or something similar, you have to use `var`. I recommend you use `lateinit var`, because this enables you to maintain null safety, as you don't need to initialize it. Lateinit is exactly what you'd think it means; late initialization. So change the declaration of your fields to:

```
private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
private lateinit var firstViewPager: ViewPager
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now the program compiles without errors. But sadly the app doesn't load the Fragments of the Tabs :/ Maybe I did something else wrong. Do you know how to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: I have put everything on GitHub, Relevant is the HomeFragment and maybe the 3 Fragments for the Tabs: https://github.com/Oribakun/tabs-inside-fragment-test